# Options to select dropdown adds n times the number of records retrieved from database

Tags: javascript, html-select

I am trying to build a login page and on successful login, list all the users in a select drop-down. I am doing the following:

1. On `document.ready`, I'm checking the login credentials as follows:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: ‘ /api/login
  ',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'post',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify(args),
  success: function(data) {
    if (!data.error) {
      console.log("You are logged in!", data.result);
      loadUsers();
    } else {
      console.log(data.error);
    }
  }
},
});
```

2. The `loadUsers()` is as below:

```js
function loadUsers() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/adminapi/getlogins',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
      if (!data.error) {
        console.log("loaded select", data.result)
        $.each(data.result, function(k, v) {
          $('<option>').val(v.loginid).text(v.firstname + "" + v.familyname)
            .appendTo('#selectLogin');
          loginUserList.push(data.result);
        });
      } else {
        console.log(data.error);
      }
    },
  });
}
```

`loginUserList` is globally defined as an empty array.

When I login, I see that the following entries in the console for `loginUserList`

```
users: (2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {loginid: 1, logintype: 2, firstname: "abc", familyname: "aaa",     email: "aa@in.com"} 
1: {loginid: 2, logintype: 1, firstname: "king", familyname: "abc", email: "king@mm.com"} 
length: 2 __proto__: Array(0)
```

But when I select an option from the dropdown, the `loginUserList` shows the following in the console.

```
users (2) [Array(2), Array(2)]
0: Array(2) 
0: {loginid: 1, logintype: 2, firstname: "abc", familyname: "aaa", email: "aa@in.com"} 
1: {loginid: 2, logintype: 1, firstname: "king", familyname: "abc", email: "king@mm.com"} 
length: 2 __proto__: Array(0) 
1: Array(2) 
0: {loginid: 1, logintype: 2, firstname: "abc", familyname: "aaa", email: "aa@in.com"} 
1: {loginid: 2, logintype: 1, firstname: "king", familyname: "abc", email: "king@mm.com"}  
length: 2 __proto__: Array(0) 
length: 2 __proto__: Array(0)
```

And the `onchange` event is as follows:

```
document.getElementById("selectLogin").addEventListener("change",function(){
 console.log("users",loginUserList)
});
```

I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Kindly help

Comment: `data.result` appears to be an array, which you are looping over with `each`, and in each iteration, pushing the entire array to `loginUserList`.

Comment: Thanks mate.. My bad, i posted such a silly thing.